# Can I have screenshot notifications persist in Android 12?

Tags: android-12, google-pixel-6

I have a Pixel 6 Pro running Android 12. In previous versions of Android (not sure which ones), unless you disabled it, taking a screenshot would create a notification that persists in the notification bar until you dismiss it.

In Android 12 there is now just a temporary dialog that floats at the bottom of the screen. If I don't react to it before it disappears, I have to navigate to my screenshots folder in Photos which takes a few seconds and is annoying.

I'd prefer the older behavior where a notification is created, is it possible to restore this in Android 12?